# JBoss 7: ClassCastException: MyCustomTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, jboss, jboss7.x, jsp-tags

Getting below exception on deploying web application that contains custom tag in JBoss server:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.taglib.MyCustomTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PerThreadTagHandlerPool.get(PerThreadTagHandlerPool.java:96) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.testAppData_jsp._jspx_meth_fx_005fsystemDate_005f0(testAppData_jsp.java:725)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.testAppData_jsp._jspService(testAppData_jsp.java:150)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
```

MyCustomTag class

```
public class MyCustomTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    ...
}
```

MyCustomTag is inheriting Tag class indirectly: MyCustomTag -> BodyTagSupport -> BodyTag -> IterationTag -> Tag

All the tag classes are packaged into jsp-api-2.1.jar and they are included in module.xml as shown below:

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com">
    <resources>
        ...
        <resource-root path="jsp-api-2.1.jar"/>
        ...
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="sun.jdk"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

I searched for conflicting jars inside jboss-eap-6.3 folder. But, BodyTagSupport class is present in only jsp-api-2.1.jar and jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar. And both the jars are compatible.

Then, why I am getting ClassCastException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's get resolved after adding `<module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api"/>` dependency in `module.xml` file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com">
    <resources>
        ...
        <resource-root path="jsp-api-2.1.jar"/>
        ...
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="sun.jdk"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

However, I don't understand, what is the need to add the dependency for `javax.servlet.jsp.api`, when `jsp-api-2.1.jar` is already added in the resource-root path of module.